# Voxeet sample app started but visiting https://localhost:8080 shows an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, videochat, video-conferencing

I've signed up `voxeet` and got my consumer key for trials.

And I added `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret` key to my `VoxeetConference.js` and started `yarn`:

```
$ yarn start

yarn run v1.19.0
$ webpack-dev-server -d --hot --inline --content-base
Project is running at https://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /      // ... omitted from here
```

It said that the project was running at localhost, but when I tried to visit localhost it showed the following errors and failed:

> ````
> OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
> internal/buffer.js:940 class FastBuffer extends Uint8Array {} ^
>
> RangeError: Invalid typed array length: -4095 at new Uint8Array () at
> new FastBuffer (internal/buffer.js:940:1) at Handle.onStreamRead [as
> onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:19) at Stream.
> (E:\kjy\itinerary\02_source\voxeet\node_modules\handle-thing\lib\handle.js:120:12)
> at Stream.emit (events.js:215:7) at endReadableNT
> (E:\kjy\itinerary\02_source\voxeet\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:1010:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
> error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command. ```
> ````

My `npm` version is `6.11.3` and node version is `12.11.1` and yarn version is `1.19.0`.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded my nodejs version to 10.15.3 (LTS) and it worked.
I downloaded the source code from https://github.com/voxeet/voxeet-web-conferencekit.git. For more info, refer to: https://github.com/voxeet/voxeet-web-conferencekit/issues/1
Special thanks to Energizz@voxeet.

Comment: For anybody that stumbles upon this question later, that answer is correct but the repository is now deprecated.  A new sample can be found here: https://github.com/voxeet/voxeet-sdk-browser-gettingstarted